# Unable to override account creation email template

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, overrides

I need to modify the welcome email sent to user upon new account creation. I need to do this in my custom module. I tried to override the function sendNewAccountEmail in Magento\Customer\Model\Customer using preference method and also using plugin method. Both were not working.

For preference method I added the following

In Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

Added Customer.php file in the location Vendor\Module\Model\Customer and added the following code

```
public function sendNewAccountEmail($type = 'registered', $backUrl = '', $storeId = '0')
{
echo "It's Working";exit;
$types = $this->getTemplateTypes();

if (!isset($types[$type])) {
    throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
        __('Please correct the transactional account email type.')
    );
}

if (!$storeId) {
    $storeId = $this->_getWebsiteStoreId($this->getSendemailStoreId());
}

$this->_sendEmailTemplate(
    $types[$type],
    'customname/email/account_email_template',
    ['customer' => $this, 'back_url' => $backUrl, 'store' => $this->getStore()],
    $storeId
);

return $this;
}
```

Still it's not taking the Customer.php file in the module.

> echo "It's Working"; is not displaying.

Please advise the correct method to follow. I tried the plugin method also. It's also not working.

Comment: You can try Admin Panel Email template setting from Marketing ->Email Template -> Add New Template

Comment: @Pritam I need to override email template in my custom module not in admin area..

Comment: Can you use your custom (assume you using a custom theme ) them instead of any custom module for this customization task?

Comment: @PritamInfo24 Actually this is custom module, sorry its not possible to use custom theme..